# why do you need to be in the specified directory when creating multi-boxes in vagrant

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I'm trying to create multiple-boxes to be loaded by vagrant when writing

```
vagrant up kali
vagrant up metasploitable2
```

The Config I have set-up are

Within the Kali VagrantFile

```
Vagrant.configure("1") do |config|

config.vm.define "kali" do |kali|
kali.vm.box = "Kali"
end
end
```

Within the Metasploitable2

```
Vagrant.configure("1") do |config|

config.vm.define "metasploitable2" do |metasploitable2|
metasploitable2.vm.box = "metasploitable2"
end
end
```

If I browse to the directory where the .vmdk and Vagrantfile are located and say

```
vagrant up kali
```

it creates the kali image, however if i'm not in the directory it won't load the VM.

with an error:

```
The machine with the name 'kali' was not found configured for
this Vagrant environment.
```

I'm going to presume this is because it's not being able to read the configuration file, but how can i make this globally because I thought you weren't supposed to modify the 'global' vagrantfile at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Vagrant has to find the Vagrantfile to read it, doesn't it? =)

So you either have to be in the same directory or any subdirectory below it. Or you can set `VAGRANT_CWD` environment variable to point to the directory. See the "Lookup Path" section in the [Vagrantfile documentation](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/index.html) for more information.

You can of course make wrapper script or other shortcuts if you need to use that often.

Btw, you might want to upgrade your Vagrantfiles to use [V2 configuration format](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/version.html) to use all new features of Vagrant 1.1+.

Comment: I was thinking Vagrant to be something else, you use a 'base' box for multiple projects and you use the vagrant file to specify what you want configured / installed on the box.. cheers for the environment variable though!

Comment: Oh wow, also didn't realize the Vagrant.configure("2") do |config| was actually specifying the version, I thought it was talking about how many boxes there were... haha not my best day. Thanks for your answer.